# NSMutableDictionary setting value crashes on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [attributes setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:86.0/255.0 green:134.0/255.0 blue:172.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

it works just fine on iOS 6, but it crashed on iOS 5. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` says:

> NSForegroundColorAttributeName
>
> > The value of this attribute is a UIColor object. Use this attribute to
> >     specify the color of the text during rendering. If you do not specify
> >     this attribute, the text is rendered in black.
> >
> > Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
> >
> > Declared in NSAttributedString.h.

So this attribute is only available in iOS 6 and later.  In fact everything in the  [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) is iOS 6 and later.

Answer (score 4):

NSForegroundColorAttributeName is available in iOS6 only.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

All of NSAttributedString is iOS6 only.